# Nodemailer gmail error after setting app password

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, google-api, environment-variables, nodemailer

I've nodejs server and mobile app with authentication feature. I'm trying to send verification email from gmail using OAuth 2.0. I've installed `nodemailer` in the server folder, generated `App Password` in my Google Account then put it in .env file (no spaces), but still getting error `Unknown error occured:Error: Invalid login: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted`

```
.env file
OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET=client secret 
OAUTH_CLIENT_ID=client id
EMAIL_ADDRESS=my email
GMAIL_PASSWORD=App Password from google account (no spaces)
GOOGLE_ACCESS_TOKEN=access token
```

Here is sender code:

```
    authRouter.post("/api/sendOtp/:sendPurpose", async (req, res) => {
      try {
        var expiryDate = Date.now() + 120000;
        let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
          service: "gmail",
          auth: {
            type: "OAuth2",
            user: process.env.EMAIL_ADDRESS,
            pass: process.env.GMAIL_PASSWORD,
            clientId: process.env.OAUTH_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET,
            refreshToken: process.env.OAUTH_REFRESH_TOKEN,
            accessToken: process.env.GOOGLE_ACCESS_TOKEN,
          },
          tls: {
            rejectUnauthorized: false,
          },
        });
     

...

await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
    await OTPSchema.create({
      email: email,
      otp: code,
      expiry: expiryDate,
    });
    setTimeout(async () => {
      await OTPSchema.deleteOne({ email: email, otp: code });
      console.log("OTP deleted successfully");
    }, expiryDate - Date.now());

    return res.status(200).json({
      message: "OTP has been sent to the provided email.",
    });
  } catch (e) {
    return res.status(500).json({
      message: `Unknown error occured:${e}`,
    });
  }
```

server's log output is:

```
OTP deleted successfully
```